# Checkbox is not checked

Tags: android

When I change a button of checkbox from xml, checkbox doesn't reflect checked.
My xml file is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/memberName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="57.56"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox"   <----- change button of checkbox
     />
```

@drawable/checkbox is png file

Comment: what is `@drawable/checkbox`? is that a png file or an xml selector? IT should be the latter with entries in it for checked and unchecked. If it is post the code for it.

Comment: @drawable/checkbox? is png file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to work `android:button` needs to be  to be set to a selector xml file that defines drawables for both checked and unchecked states. Try setting it up like this:

**checkbox_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

where `checkbox_checked.png` is the image you want to use when the box is checked. and `checkbox_unchecked.png` is the image when it is not checked.

Then in your main layout set the button like this:

```
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/checkbox"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
 />
```